# Spring Boot Changing Values From a Controller To Another

Tags: java, algorithm, controller

I'm having an issue with 2 controllers and i'm not sure if there is a solution for this.
I extract some ads from the internet(thousands of ads) and i can't extract all of them at once because it will take too long to load all those ads on the page.
Basically the first controller is a POST controller which returns **always** let's say the first 5 elements from that list and it looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search1" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List search1(){
     List<?> list1 = scrapper1.search1():
     return list1;
}
```

The second controller returns the next 5 elements per execution(until the end of the list and then it starts from the first 5 elements) from the same list but it's a different method, let's say this controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List search2(){
    List<?> list2 = scrapper2.search2();
    return list2;
}
```

My problem is that if the second method is executed let's say 3 times the page will contain elements from that list which are from 10-15 and if the first method gets executed again the page will contain elements from 0-5 but now if the second method gets executed it will jump to elements from 15-20.I need those 2 controllers because i have 2 buttons on the page and there are multiple lists..I need somehow to reset the second method whenever the first method from the first controller gets executed.Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of problem we can use PagingAndSortingRepository from spring data.